# Brasero stuck at 'Normalizing tracks'

Tags: brasero

I am trying to burn an audio CD using Brasero. With all albums I've tried to burn, Brasero gets stuck at `Normalizing tracks`:

[image]

Answer (score 29, accepted):

This is a known [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/brasero/+bug/374101). The workaround for this problem is to disable the normalization plugin.

In Brasero, go to `edit` and click `Plugins`. Remove the checkmark for `Normalization`.

[image: Plugins Window]

Comment: +1 for the usefulness and answering your own question when no one did..

Comment: @Joren You saved my ass on Christmas Eve. I owe you a Christmas present.

Answer (score 5):

**Solved!!!**

```
sudo apt-get install normalize-audio
```

The problem is that the dependency with the normalization software is not included. If you install it by hand, brasero will work normally.