# I want to install an iso dvd burner, but I don't know, which application I need to use for it

Tags: installation

I'm new to Ubuntu, could someone help me with an installer application? I have a 12.04 LTS...

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Brasero](https://projects.gnome.org/brasero/).

Some of its features:

- Image Burning
- Data CD/DVD
- Audio CD
- CD/DVD copy

You can install it by using Ubuntu's Software Center.

Comment: Brasero has a not-so-good reviews and ratings... But basically I need a program to open any downloads from the net...

Comment: It only has a bad rating because of a bug when burning audio CD's which is easily solvable. Brasero has always worked fine for me.

Comment: Can it burn ISO files too? And do you know how to solve the bug issue/

Comment: It burns ISO files as stated in my answer. The bug can be solved like this: http://askubuntu.com/questions/325269/brasero-stuck-at-normalizing-tracks

Comment: Thanks, I will try it... But still want to know, which program I need to select to open a downloaded file from the net, if I choose to do that...

Comment: `open a downloaded file`. What kind of file do you mean?

Comment: Install a software from the net. Like that dvd burner, for example...

Comment: In Ubuntu, you use the software center or the terminal to install software. For more information see https://help.ubuntu.com/community/InstallingSoftware

Answer (score 0):

You can install [IsoMount](http://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/furiusisomount/) from the software center to mount and open .iso files

[Brasero Disk Burner](http://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/brasero/) to make CD/DVD.

The program which you can choose depends on the extension of a file.

Answer (score 0):

For data discs and ISO's I think [K3B](http://www.k3b.org/) is the way to go.  It also works very well for audio CD's. I have also used Brasero it's pretty simple.

To install K3B, click [**K3B** [image: Install comixcursors-lefthanded]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/k3b/).

Also you can try Nero, to install it, download the DEB file from [Nero](http://www.nero.com/enu/downloads-linux4-update.php).  Once downloded, just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, navigate to the downloads folder, and run the command(s) below:

```
sudo dpkg -i <file_name>.deb
```